# Not sure why program doesn't terminate

Tags: c, string, loops

If you look down at the main function, the error lies at the first input.
When I type \q, my program does not terminate as I had hoped it would.

Can anyone explain to me why this might be happening?

I noticed if I change fgets to scanf, then the \q part works just fine, but then (with scanf) my input is terminated after a space if I enter a string with any spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>


int count(char *input, char c) {
    int k = strlen(input); 
    return 0; 
}



void subanagram() {
    char yes[50] = "yes"; 
    char no [50] = "no"; 
    char play[100]; 
    char sa[100]; 
    char strin[100];
    char quitt[75] = { '/', 'q', '\0'}; 

    do {
    printf("Would you like to play the sub-anagram game?"); 

    //scanf("%s", play); 
    fgets(play, 100, stdin); 

    if(stricmp(play, yes) == 0) {
        printf("Enter a potential sub-anagram (or /q to quit): "); 
        scanf("%s", sa); 

        if(stricmp(sa, quitt) == 0) {
            break; 
        }

    }




}
while (stricmp(yes, play) == 0 || stricmp(no, play) == 0); 
}

void main() {
    char string[100];
    char pally[75];
    char nospace[100];
    char reversed[100]; 
    char yes[75] = {'y', 'e', 's', '\0'}; 
    char quit[75] = { '\\', 'q', '\0'}; 
    char no[75] = {'n', 'o', '\0'}; 
    char play[50]; 
    int p, i, k, j=0; 

    printf("Enter a word or phrase (or \\q to quit): "); 
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);  
    //scanf("%s", string);

    k = strlen(string); 

    if(stricmp(quit, string) == 0) {
        printf("Thank you for using my program!\n"); 
        return; 
    }

    do {
      printf("Would you like to see if the phrase is a palindrome?"); 
      scanf("%s", pally); 
    } while (stricmp(yes, pally) == 1 || stricmp(no, pally) == 1); 

    if(stricmp(yes, pally) == 0) {


        for(i=0; i<k; i++) {
            if(!isspace(string[i]) == 1) {

                nospace[j] = string[i];
                nospace[j+1] = '\0'; 
                j++;

        }
    }
                strcpy(reversed, nospace); 
                strrev(reversed); 

                if(stricmp(nospace, reversed) == 0) {
                    printf("The phrase %s IS a palindrome.\n", string);
                    subanagram(); 
                }

                else { printf("The phrase %s IS NOT a palindrome.\n", string); 
                    subanagram(); 
                }


    }
        if(stricmp(pally, no) == 0) {
    /*  printf("Would you like to play the sub-anagram game?");
        scanf("%s", play); 
        if(strcmp(play, yes) == 0) {
            subanagram(); 
        }*/
        subanagram();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: please indent your code (which btw is too large fo SO), so it is readable and one can see the corresponding blocks!

Answer (score 0):

hmm, on first looking in this (much too) large program my symetric detector sees in subanagram():

```
{ '/', 'q',
"...(or /q to quit): "
```

and in main it is:

```
char quit[75] = { '\\', 'q',
```

and your question is:

```
"When I type \q, my program does not"
```

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` (character as newline) as a string that you enter will be included in the case of `fgets(stinrg, 100, stdin)` Unlike `scanf("%s", string)`. So, the quit string change to `char quit[] = "\\q\n"` or you delete the last `\n'`, it is determined must be a treatment, such as if you like.